# C++ Lambda causing 'candidate function not viable:'

Tags: c++, lambda, emscripten

Why would the following lambda not adhere to the signature when adding a capture element?

```
[&callback](unsigned handle, void* userData, void* data, unsigned size) -> void { ... }
```

but this would?

```
[](unsigned handle, void* userData, void* data, unsigned size) -> void { ... }
```

Signature:

```
typedef void (*em_async_wget2_data_onload_func)(unsigned, void*, void*, unsigned);
```

Answer (score 7):

Lambdas with captures can not be simply converted to function pointers. For maximum flexibility (but not performance) consider the use of `std::function<void(unsigned,void*,void*,unsigned)>`

Answer (score 3):

Only captureless [lambdas](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) can be converted to a pointer to a function.